# Sorting Array of Arrays having variable number of elements

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

I have to sort an array of arrays. I've searched for solutions however my problem is:

1. need to sort arrays that may have different sizes from a script run to another.
2. need to sort not only by one or two elements, but, if possible based in all elements.

For example, for the following inputs:

```
[[2,3,4,5,6],[1,3,4,5,7],[1,3,4,5,8]]
[[5,2,3],[2,2,4],[2,2,5]]
```

The output should be, respectively:

```
[[1,3,4,5,7],[1,3,4,5,8],[2,3,4,5,6]]
[[2,2,4],[2,2,5],[5,2,3]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Do as below

```
input=[[2,3,4,5,6],[1,3,4,5,7],[1,3,4,5,8]] 
input.sort # => [[1, 3, 4, 5, 7], [1, 3, 4, 5, 8], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
```